# Output basic compound interest as a list into MessageBox using for loop

Tags: for-loop, messagebox

I need to output basic compound interest that will be displayed in a message box using for loop

The message box needs to show a left column titled "Years" and a right column showing "Amount".

My code only displays the messagebox 5 times whereas I need it to all be displayed in a list

Here is what I have so far:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        decimal amount;
        decimal principal = 1000;
        double rate = 0.05;
        string msg;
        msg = "Years \t Amount";
        msg += Environment.NewLine;



        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
        {
            amount = principal * ((decimal)Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year));
            msg += amount.ToString("C");
            msg  += Environment.NewLine;





        }

        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Compund Interest");
```

Comment: Do you want the message box to show 5 times with the list adding a new row each time or display one time with the finished list of 5 rows?

Comment: Display one time with the finished list of 5 rows

Comment: Ok you don't won't to show the messagebox five times so that should probably move.  You do want to build a string to show in that messagebox appending to it five times so that should probably go where?

Comment: I think I need to move it outside of the loop but then it loses the "amount" value

Comment: Well you don't lose the "amount" value but it only has the value of the last calculation because it is overwritten every iteration. Instead build a string, maybe using string builder, and append to it each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I understand and I am grateful for your help.  I have not come across string builder in my class yet.  The only iteration of string we have used is ToString and string.  I am not sure how to build the message box with what we have learned so far.

Comment: Well you can always build a string by using mystring += mystring.  You can add a newline (return) to a string by mystring+=Environment.NewLine

Comment: Work on it and post an edit to your code showing the new code if you are still having difficulty.

Comment: I updated it but I cannot figure out what you mean by mystring += mystring. I realize I have to make a new string outside of it I just cannot seem to get the data from the for loop then format it properly in a messagebox.  Should I just drop this course, I just can't seem to get this.

Comment: @RyanMcCloy : You've stored the discrete value of amount in `msg` (its value at this loop step) That's good ! You know what ? An assignement (`msg = amount.ToString("C");`) **replaces** the initial value by another. An addition on the other hand does what ? Tell me...

Comment: No your almost there msg = ammount.ToString("C") replaces the value if you use += instead it will append it.  Then what you are missing is your year number and column headers and carriage returns. So start the string outside the loop adding the column headers and a carriage return bu using  += Environment.Newline to the string you are building. In the loop build your string with year number += amount += Environment.NewLine. You'll want some white spaces in between.  It will make sense to you when you get it all together

Comment: I have the columns going (yay)  But the amount is only going down the years column.  I need a years column going form 1-5 then the amount in the amount column

Comment: were you able to finish the assignment? Don't give up on the class you can always come here for help as long as your questions are asked properly and you have tried and provided the code you have created.

Comment: Still couldn't figure out the final code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        decimal amount;
        decimal principal = 1000;
        double rate = 0.05;
        string msg;
        // start building string here i.e. msg = "header \t header"  \t places a tab
        // add a carriage return msg += Enviornment.Newline
        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++)
        {
            amount = principal * ((decimal)Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year));
            // don't overwrite msg but append to it msg += "year number use your counter \t" += what you are already doing below.
            msg = amount.ToString("C");
           // then add your carriage return again.


        }
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string amount = "";
    decimal principal = 1000;
    double rate = 0.05;

    for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++) {
        amount += string.Format("{0:C}", principal * Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year))) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(amount, "Compound Inerest");
}
```

Comment: especially when its clearly a homework assignment it would be nicer to try and teach something instead of just posting an answer with no explanation.

Comment: Your answer gets me closer but I also need a column to the left that displays each ear as it goes down as well as Column headers that display Year and AMount

Comment: @RyanMcCloy try to work through it yourself with some hints instead of just copying someones code

Comment: Yeah I won't copy it, still trying to figure this out else I won't even remember

Comment: @RyanMcCloy : I've shown you how to move the messagebox outside the loop, how to change a variable to a string (because you can't add lines to a decimal) and how to append a new line. Like new lines, what else can't you append to a decimal ? Or put in other words, what would you change/add/remove in the code above to show years and amounts, well formatted in the messagebox ?

Comment: @RyanMcCloy : Don't use string.Format, use `.ToString` instead since it's appropriate with what you've learned. By the way, better keep decimal Type for amount and use another string to store the list...

Comment: I still can't figure out what string to make outside of the for loop that will contain all the data in one message box with the proper formatting

Comment: @RyanMcCloy Leading you to answer that yourself.. : _How you've come to decide the use of four valiables, namely `amount`, `principal`, `rate` and `msg` ?_ If you know why/how, then your _should_ be able to figure out if you have enough variables to reach you goal.